# Convergence of infinite-dimensional random variables

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables

For every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and every measurable $E \subseteq [0,1]$, the object $f_n(E)$ is a random variable that takes real values. The sequence ($f_n$) can thus be understood as a sequence of infinite-dimensional random variables.

Suppose that, for every $E \subseteq [0,1]$, $f_n(E)$ converges almost surely to a random variable $x(E)$. Defining $f_{\infty}$ by $f_{\infty}(E)=x(E)$, is it correct to say that the sequence of random variables $f_n$ converges (pointwise) to the random variable $f_{\infty}$? Are there other notions of convergence in that case? Would it be possible to define a notion of strong convergence by considering an appropriate metric on the space of probabiity distributions? Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by the first paragraph? Common definition of random variable is a measurable function from the sample space to reals, and in that sense $f_n(E)$ would be interpreted as image of $E$ under mapping $f_n$, and thus it is not a real number and the rest of your question does not make sense in this view. Also, what do you mean by "infnite dimensional" r.v.?

Comment: @user160738 Each $f_n$ is defined on $\mathcal E\times\Omega$ where $(\Omega,\mathcal F)$ is your favorite measurable space and $\mathcal E$ is the sigma-algebra on $[0,1]$ to which every $E$ belongs. Thus, for every $E$ in $\mathcal E$, $f_n(E):\Omega\to\mathbb R$, $\omega\mapsto f_n(E,\omega)$ is a bona fide random variable.

Comment: @user160738 Exactly. Thanks Did for the clarification.